# McNemar power test calculation in R (power.mcnemar.test function tuning)

Tags: r, statistics

I have a question regarding the tuning of the power.mcnemar.test() function in R (MESS package).

I have a hypothetical example of a treatment (100 individuals) in total (paired design).

-Before the treatment, 60 individuals are sick, 40 are not
-After the treatment, 30 individuals are sick, 70 are not

Following an implementation of the two way table below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOrOB.png)

The OR (psi) that I calculate is 0.2857 ('psi' parameter in R function).

However, I am not sure what should be the ('paid' parameter)?

The description given in the help is : "The probability that a case patient is not exposed and that the corresponding control patient was exposed"

Given that I have a paired design, what should I tune

-Should it be 30%, given that 30% of individuals have changed status?
-Should it be 50%, as we passed from 60% D+ to 30% D+?
-Or should it be something else?

Thank you very much for your clarifications

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.